# Having trouble completing paypal payin3 transaction

Tags: paypal

I have integrated paypal payin3 (paylater) option on my website. I am testing it on sandbox when I try to complete the process at the end it shows an error which I am not able to fix despite I spent many hours to fix it. Anyone has an idea how to fix it. see the below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a sandbox problem. If the PayPal page is opening normally and regular PayPal payments work (not selecting Pay in 3), then there's nothing more you need to do.